# chrome.windows.create: why callback Win is background page instead of new window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension.

In background script, I create a popup window (popup.html) and I want to pass a value to a function in popup.js (which is embedded in popup.html).

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("html/popup.html"),
        type: "popup"
    }, function(win) {
    // Do sth after window opens
        win.funcionInPopupJS(value);
    });
});
```

An error message is shown. Error handling response: TypeError: win.funcionInPopupJS is not a function at background.js

Why? Besides, how to call the function in popup.js?

Comment: The API returns its [own type of window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-Window), not related to JavaScript `window` object. Use a different approach: [Pass data or modify extension html in a new tab/window](//stackoverflow.com/a/54715122)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just have one more question. If I get my popup window using chrome.extension.getViews, I can call the function in popup.js. I think callback Win should be same in both cases (except one is single Win and another one is array). E.g. let popupTab = chrome.extension.getViews({tabId: Number(popupTabId)})[0];  popupTab.funcionInPopupJS(value);

Comment: No, it's different as you can see in the documentation.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for your answer again.